# Buttons not displaying images

Tags: html

My website was working fine before I added more code and features.
It may be because of the tags around the code.
I would like to know how to fix the buttons with numbers (the Cool Music button works fine).
[My website is here](http://abhijith.hol.es)

```html
<script>
function btnClicked()
{
 var audio = new Audio('http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_lkfhhpM4M41qcmhugo1.mp3');
  audio.playbackRate = 2.5;
  audio.loop = true;
  audio.play();
}
function changeImage1()
{
 document.getElementById("image").src= "https://media0.giphy.com/media/sIIhZliB2McAo/200.gif";
}


function changeImage2()
{
 document.getElementById("image").src= "https://www.clicktorelease.com/code/gif/1.gif";
}

function changeImage3()
{
 document.getElementById("image").src= "http://www.kizoa.com/img/e8nZC.gif";
}

function changeImage4()
{
 document.getElementById("image").src= "http://www.netanimations.net/flying_pig_by_rutabaga.gif";
}
</script>
<button onclick="btnClicked()">
Cool Music
</button>
<button onclick="changeImage1()">1</button>
<button onclick="changeImage2()">2</button>
<button onclick="changeImage3()">3</button>
<button onclick="changeImage4()">4</button>
```

Comment: What precisely is the problem?

Comment: You are using `document.getElementById("image")` but looking at your source code, there is no element with the ID image.

Comment: Your website has lot's of errors. Check header source. You can't have `h1`/`FONT` in head section. Also `<script>` must have `type="text/javascript"` because otherwise browser will ignore it.

Comment: @Justinas That is not exactly true. The browser won't ignore javascript if `type="text/javascript"` is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer. But this could lead you to the answer.
You have `document.getElementById("image").src="<some url>";` in your `changeImage` functions. But you don't have any DOM element with ID as **image**. Please check your console and you can find the error yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an element called Image, but from looking through your code I can't find an element with the id of Image.

In the console it shows: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null". This means that it couldn't find the DOM element you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `document.getElementById("image")` but looking at your source code, there is no element with the ID image.